# What is required to play online on the Xbox 360 version of Borderlands?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands, xbox-network

I've bought Borderlands and I've been playing it on my own. I'm starting to get interested in playing co-op online, but never done it before so not sure how I go about it.

- Do I need to do anything else other than the game & an Internet connection?
- Do I just click on the Xbox live link in the game load screen to take me to the correct online location/screen etc?
- Do I need to buy an Xbox live card to be able to go online?

A real newbie question but I've never played online, not sure how it works, and not sure if I'll prefer it to the single player I'm going through now. I don't want to pay loads of additional cash for Xbox live access and then not use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is the game,internet and Xbox live gold membership.

To start it, click "Xbox live" in the main menu.

 - Click custom games or quick match to join someone else's game. Pick the match you want to join and then it will ask you to choose your character. Everyones matches to choose from will be labeled by what level character they are and what quest they are working on.
 
 - Click Create game to start a game with your character.

Comment: Thanks. I'll pop out and get a gold card then. I imagine I'll enjoy it enough to keep playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play online with an Xbox, you must have Xbox Live gold service. No two ways about it.

The only exception to this rule is Phantasy Star Universe. You are not technically required to pay for xbox live, but you are limited in communication options. But with that game you pay extra per month either way for the connection to the PSU servers.

Comment: Thought as much. Just wasn't quite sure if a game didn't come with a few hours of free time, or something to get people hooked to playing on line. I'll need to get myself one of those gold memeberships.

Comment: Final Fantasy XI is another game that doesn't require a gold membership. AFAIK all MMOs are exempt from that requirement.